# How to set listener for only walking activities in Google fit api

Tags: google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I need to add sensor listener for Walking activity in android google fit. can any one guide me in right way.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot add listener for only walking but we can create listener for steps and from that we can get walking activity only.